# In Plain/Pure Javascript, how do you find out what available methods or properties an element object has?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Using only pure javascript without jquery, how do you display all the possible methods and properties of an element object? Say I have the body object - document.getElementByTagName('body')[0]

How do I list out all the possible methods I can use? And what properties it has? I know I can use .click() and .setAttribute but what else is there?

How would I find out using the Chrome console?

Comment: In the browser consoles it's extremely easy; in fact it's hard to even describe since when a variable has as its value a reference to an object - including a DOM node - then the console shows that pretty clearly. You can "open" the object to see its properties.

Comment: how do you open the object?

Comment: If you want to just look at a random DOM element, you can do this in Chrome. Bring up the developer tools, and choose the "Elements" view. Click the magnifier and select one of the nodes in your page by clicking on it so that it turns blue. Then you can go to the "Console" view and type, `console.dir($0)`.  That'll let you click on the result and "open" the view of the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log), I'd suggest [`console.dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.dir)

```
console.dir(myObj);
```

`dir` will show your *Object's* properties even if you pass a *Node*, rather than showing the tree-view in the console, which will happen with `log` if it recognises the *Object* as a *Node*.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you want to log the object to the console:

```
console.log(MyObjectInstance);
```

Then when you open chrome developer tools you can go to 'console' and view your object. There should be a little arrow next to the logged object that you can click to view all of its methods and attributes.